# Should there be a chatroom dedicated to language exchange?

Tags: discusión, chat

As I have seen on Latin language stackexchange forum, there they have a chatroom where they talk in Latin. So I think it could be good if there was such chatroom dedicated for only language exchange by everybody is talking in Spanish.

Comment: It already exists! See [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia)

Comment: Oh OK Thank you for your comment. I did not see it because It was full of RSS messages :)

Comment: It used to have a bunch of participants for some time, but now it is a bit idle